# Two factor SSH authentication on multiple servers

Tags: authentication, two-factor, two-factor-authentication

I am a newbie when it comes to Two factor authentication. I have the general idea of implementing two factor authentication on a single server. But I was wondering if there is a standard solution for implementing it on multiple servers.

**SCENARIO:**

So, there a bunch of *nix machines (around 50) for which I want to enable two factor authentication. If I enable 2 factor ssh authentication using google authenticator (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-two-factor-authentication) on all machines, it doesn't seem like a good idea to generate and keep track of individual auth codes. Is there any way I can simplify the whole process.

**EX:**
Is there a way I can use two factor ssh authentication once and forward it with my ssh requests to all machines? Like a proxy machine which can handle OAuth for rest of my stack? Also are there existing systems/softwares/services in place which, can make the implementation easier? I am open to new architectural designs as well.

Thanks in advance!

**PS:**
We are currently using ssh-key based authentication on all our machines

Comment: You write "*use two factor ssh authentication once and forward it with my ssh requests to all machines*" - but the core concept of two-factor authentication is that the data from the hardware token is usable only once, or if reusable, only for a very short period.  So even if you could do this, it would be pointless - if it worked, it wouldn't be true two-factor authentication.  Mary's suggestion is probably your best bet - have two-factor authentication to the only machine that's generally accessible, then use ssh key-based authentication, and ssh-agent on the clients, from then on in.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve in a pure security perspective is to install a second lock on your doors so you can open wide all your windows. So with that in mind, I think that project would be better justified if the reasoning was to ease the operation's burden, not to increase security.

Answer (score 1):

If your primary goal is to authenticate once and have access to all your machines without having to re-authenticate, you could use hostkey-based authentication from your jump-off host:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server.

(Apologies if you already knew about this option.)

Comment: Hi Mary,
Thanks for replying; we are already using ssh-key based authentication as you said. We wanted to keep the same flow albeit factoring in more security by using two factor over ssh.

Comment: Oh, sorry, misunderstood the objective there.  Actually, you can do key+password authentication two ways:  one is to put a passphrase on your local key store.  The other is to require both a key and a password for the server connection (available since 6.2):  https://sysconfig.org.uk/two-factor-authentication-with-ssh.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have isolated network (no one can use your subnet), you can disable public SSH access for all machines (let us call these as private machines) except one/two machines (public machines).

The public machines have two factor authentication.

The private machines don't have two factor authentication. The private machines SSH port is only accessible from a certain IP (your subnet for example, or public machines IP).

This way is usually people do in AWS environment with public-private subnet. Instances with only private IP only accessible from instances which have public access.

So, whenever you want to access your private machines, you need to login to a public machine first. And then, from there, you can login to any machines.